# Kafka-MATLAB integration 'Received unexpected handshake message'

Tags: matlab, ssl, apache-kafka

I am currently trying to connect MATLAB via my desktop (windows 11) to a server on 'AWS' via Kafka. I am, however, getting the following error message in MATLAB:
Error using webread
Error connecting to http://localhost:61402/consumer/messages?topic=scratch.tiod.inmotion-01: Failed to connect to localhost
port 61402 after 2212 ms: Couldn't connect to server
and this error on my broker:
tls: received unexpected handshake message of type *tls.clientHelloMsg when waiting for *tls.certificateMsg" .
I have used the following code which should allow me to at least make a proper connection, but it already goes wrong with the handshake. all variables are have the proper values, as the same parameters yield positive results from a .go application and the computer CLI. Might there be a problem in this configuration or do I need to add something else?

```
dataKS = kafkaStream(kafkaHost, kafkaPort, TOPIC, ...
    "group.id", GROUP_ID, ...
    "client.id", CLIENT_ID, ...
    "security.protocol", "ssl", ...
    "ssl.truststore.type", "SSL", ...
    "ssl.key.location", PKI_KEY, ... 
    "ssl.certificate.location", PKI_CERT, ...
    "ssl.ca.location", PKI_CACERT, ...
    "enable.ssl.certificate.verification" , "true");

tt1 = readtimetable(dataKS);
```

I tried to turn off certification, to include different cert-files, to change the topic. However, this all led to the same errors everytime, so I expect something going wrong in the matlab configurations.